# Change the Visibility section default value to customer for a lightning action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

I have a salesforce lightning action, where there is a visibility field Customer\Internal. Currently, the default value is set to be Internal. I need to change it to Customer in the lightning component. 
[image]

[image]

```
    <aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <c:ServiceAction recordId="{!v.recordId}" action="Escalate to Engineering" />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: We will need to see the code that you have in `c:serviceAction` which supposedly renders the picklist field here. If it's in that component, you will need to accordingly change the code in there.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that, but anyway thanks Jayant. it's working now